# Moving to Switzerland as a student

Tags: working-visas, students, switzerland

I am looking for some advice regarding the regulations in Switzerland.

I am going to study in Switzerland for a master's degree, and I plan to move there with my girlfriend (both Romanian citizens) around the end of August 2018. She will work during this time. The duration of my master's degree is 2 years.

Switzerland has a quota for the number of work permits for Romanian and Bulgarian citizens from 1 June 2017. It seems like this quota has been put for 1 year. What happens if she applies for a residence/work permit after June 2018? Will her application still be subject to the quota?

I own a car registered in Romania. Being a student, what are the regulations on importing the car? Would it be possible to use it without getting Swiss plates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What happens if she applies for a residence/work permit after June 2018? Will her application still be subject to the quota?**

It doesn't seems so, because, as you stated: ([link](https://www.ch.ch/en/working-switzerland-eu-efta/#bulgaria-and-romania-eu-2))

> This measure is in force for a year.

So following the logic, from the 1st of June 2018 you will benefit from the same rights as other EU citizens.

**What are the regulations on importing the car? Would it be possible to use it without getting Swiss plates?** ([link](https://www.ch.ch/en/importations-cars-switzerland))

> Vehicles belonging to people moving to Switzerland (that had been used for at least six months abroad) are duty free.
>
> After you have cleared customs, you need to register your vehicle at the road traffic office in your canton of residence

**But**, you are a student: (emphasis by me)

> Foreign workers, **students** and interns may use their foreign vehicles on which duty has not been paid in Switzerland. **However, a customs permit is needed for this.**

After some search, it looks like you need to (when crossing the border with your car) declare yourself at the customs office at the border to get a customs permit. Beware of [working hours](http://www.pwebapps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/dst/?lang=4)!